# Adding 2 fields to 2 content types give: the object has been updated by another user since it was last fetched

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to add 2 new fields to 2 existing content types and I am having this exception, not sure how to fix it tho

Exception is thrown after the 1st content type update in the line: agendaPoints.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, fldRecurrent);

```
private void AddRecurrentAndCopyAttachmentsFieldsToContentType(SPWeb currentWeb)
        {

            try
            {
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPContentType agendaPointsProposedCT = currentWeb.ContentTypes[Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_NAME];
                SPContentType agendaPoints = currentWeb.ContentTypes[Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINT_NAME];

                string recurrentFieldName = currentWeb.Fields.Add(Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSRECURRENT_NAME, SPFieldType.Boolean, false);
                SPField recurrentField = currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(recurrentFieldName);

                string copyAttachmentsFieldName = currentWeb.Fields.Add(Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSCOPYATTACHMENTS_NAME, SPFieldType.Boolean, false);
                SPField copyAttachmentsField = currentWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(recurrentFieldName);

                SPField fldRecurrent = currentWeb.Fields[Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSRECURRENT_NAME];
                SPField fldCopyAttachments = currentWeb.Fields[Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSCOPYATTACHMENTS_NAME];

                agendaPointsProposedCT.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, fldRecurrent);
                agendaPointsProposedCT.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, fldCopyAttachments);
                MoveFieldInColumnOrder(currentWeb, Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_NAME, fldRecurrent.InternalName, 1);
                MoveFieldInColumnOrder(currentWeb, Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINTPROPOSED_NAME, fldCopyAttachments.InternalName, 2);
                agendaPointsProposedCT.Update();

                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                agendaPoints.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, fldRecurrent);
                agendaPoints.AddFieldRefFromContentType(currentWeb, fldCopyAttachments);                
                MoveFieldInColumnOrder(currentWeb, Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINT_NAME, fldRecurrent.InternalName, 1);
                MoveFieldInColumnOrder(currentWeb, Meetings.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINT_NAME, fldCopyAttachments.InternalName, 2);
                agendaPoints.Update();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }

        }
```

**and the extension method**

```
public static void AddFieldRefFromContentType(this SPContentType contentType, SPWeb web,SPField field)
        {
            SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(web.AvailableFields.GetField(field.InternalName));
            //Check if the Field reference exists
            if (!contentType.Fields.ContainsField(field.Title))
            {
                contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);
                contentType.Update(true);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the line that gets the content type to the line above/below the Allow Unsafe updates.  Also is there any type of inheritance setup between the content types?

Comment: indeed the problem is not in the code, the problem is that actually agenda points was inheriting from agenda points proposed content type, so I had to add the fields only once to the parent content type and thats it.  thanks for helping me find out the problem :), post the answer I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving the line that gets the content type to the line above/below the Allow Unsafe updates. Also is there any type of inheritance setup between the content types?